# How to convert a Javascript object with nested functions into a Python Class?

Tags: javascript, python, json, class, nested

Trying to convert this code below into a Python class. Would I need to nest a System class within the original class? Confused on how to go about this. I want to call `MainClass.System.GetInstance().GetLibraryVersion()`, as an example

```
{
  System: {
    GetInstance: () => {
      return {
        GetLibraryVersion: () => {
          return {
            major: 0,
            minor: 0,
            type: '',
            build: ''
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: trying to convert a function from one language to another is out of my reach. You could try to serialize it in some way, but I don't know how. maybe a library exists that does this kind of things between javascript and python

Answer (score 0):

The answer:

```
class MainClass:
def __init__(self):
    self.System = self.System()

class System():
    def __init__(self):
        self.major = 0
        self.minor = 0
        self.type = ''
        self.build = ''

    def GetInstance(self):
        return self

    def GetLibraryVersion(self):
        return self
```